# Run "should_panic" tests with different inputs

Tags: testing, rust, panic

Assume the following function which gets the nth bit from a `u8`:

```rust
    fn get_bit(&self, n: u8) -> bool {
        if n > 7 {
            panic!("Overflow detected while using `get_bit`: Tried to get the {n}th bit.");
        }
        let result = *self >> n & 1;
        if result == 1 {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The basic (panic-case) test looks like this:

```
#[test]
#[should_panic]
fn get_bit_panic_ut() {
    0b0000_0000.get_bit(8);
}
```

As you can see this only tests for 8 as input. I want to make sure that this function will panic for any input between 8 and 255. So my naive attempt was:

```
#[test]
#[should_panic]
fn get_bit_panic_ut() {
    for i in 8..=255 {
        println!("{i}"); // For demonstration purposes
        0b0000_0000.get_bit(i);
    }
}
```

If I run the above with the `--nocapture` flag, I can see that the test execution stops after 8. So my question is how do I test for all the other cases here?

One option I came across, which might work is the [rtest crate](https://crates.io/crates/rstest). I wonder if rust provides any out of the box mechanics for scenarios like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - but you can easily simulate it:

```rust
#[test]
fn get_bit_panic_ut() {
    for i in 8..=255 {
        println!("{i}"); // For demonstration purposes
        assert!(std::panic::catch_unwind(|| 0b0000_0000.get_bit(i)).is_err());
    }
}
```